# How to connect to this curl string in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to connect to an app called knowbe4 in Python. However, I don't know how to convert the curl string into a python request.

Here is the curl string:

```
 curl -k -X GET   'https://us.api.knowbe4.com'   -H 'Authorization: Bearer 454yrghrtwehsthvNPXM'
```

Here is my code:

```
import json
import requests
from config import configs
from exceptions import ConfigurationError, HTTPError

    url='https://us.api.knowbe4.com'
    t='454yrghrtwehsthvNPXM'
    
    h={'Authorization': 'Bearer {0}'.format(t)}
    
    resp = requests.get(url, headers=h, verify=False)
```

When I run this nothing happens. Am i doing something wrong? I am new to api calls so any information would help.

Error that i am getting:

```
NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00050>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))
```

Comment: What do you *expect* to happen? Are you examining the value of `resp` at all? It's not going to automatically print the response to standard output like `curl` does.

Comment: have you tried `print(resp.text)`? What do you mean by "Nothing has happened"

Comment: see error message

Comment: Your script is working fine for me. I'm getting response code 200 but the response text says `Access Denied` - May be token problem